# SwiftUI ForEach View does not update when underlying @StateObject dictionary is updated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, foreach

Here are the pieces. I'm trying to have the UI button update the data in `Data` and have SwiftUI automatically update another sibling View (that is based on the `Data` model). The `Data` model dict is updated, but the Cell view in `ForEach` does not update.

```
// main view (ContentView)

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var data = Data()
    @State private var cells: [Int: [Cell]] = [:]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Debug me")

            if let items = cells[0] {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    item
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            setup()
        }
    }

    private func setup() {
        var newData: [Cell] = []
        newData.append(Cell(key: "A", data: data, text: "1"))
        newData.append(Cell(key: "B", data: data, text: "2"))
        newData.append(Cell(key: "C", data: data, text: "3"))
        cells[0] = newData
    }
}
```

```
// child view (Cell)

import SwiftUI

struct Cell: View, Hashable, Identifiable {
    @State private var key = ""
    @ObservedObject private var data: Data

    @State var text: String

    init(key: String, data: Data, text: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.data = data
        self.text = text
    }

    // Identifiable
    var id: String {
        return "\(key)\(text)"
    }

    // Hashable
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(key)
        hasher.combine(text)
    }

    // Equatable
    static func ==(lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key && lhs.text == rhs.text
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(key)
            Text(" / ")
            Text(text)
            Button(action: confirm) {
                Label("", systemImage: "checkmark")
            }
        }
    }

    private func confirm() {
        // contrived example
        // this does not work
        data.updateValue(key: "C", value: "updated123")
    }

}
```

```
// data class (Data)

import SwiftUI

class Data: ObservableObject {

    @Published var data: [String:String]

    init() {
        data = [:]
    }

    func updateValue(key: String, value: String) {
        data[key] = value
        objectWillChange.send()
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but do not name a custom class `Data`. It could interfere with Foundation `Data`.

Comment: The issue is most likely caused by the wrong initialization of the property wrappers in `Cell`. Delete the occurrences of `private` and the `init` method.

Comment: In your `Cell` view you have no relationship between `text` and the observed object. Updates happens but you are not making use of them. Try to change `text` from a @State property to a computed property and see what happens. `var text: String { data.data[key] ?? "" }`

Comment: Sidenote: The `objectWillChange.send()` in `updateValue()` is both unnecessary (updating the `data` of the `@Published` will do this for you already) and incorrect (it is _willChange_, not didChange, it would be too late for SwiftUI to grab the old value).

Comment: Generally I wouldn't ever put `View`s into a `State`, that is probably causing the biggest issues here. Rather call the `Cell` within the `ForEach` with the current values of your observable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above the `Cell` view doesn't make use of the observed object so that it and the other properties are completely independent of each other.

Below is my version of `Cell` where I have made `text` into a computed property since this is actually what it represent, the value you get from the observed objects published property given the `key` value.

```
struct Cell: View, Hashable, Identifiable {
    @State private var key = ""
    @ObservedObject private var data: DataModel

    var text: String { data.data[key] ?? "" }

    init(key: String, data: DataModel, text: String) {
        self.key = key
        data.data[key] = text
        self.data = data
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(key)
            Text(" / ")
            Text(text)
            Button(action: { confirm(key) }) {
                Label("", systemImage: "checkmark")
            }
        }
    }

    private func confirm(_ key: String) {
        data.updateValue(key: key, value: "\(Int.random(in: 1...100))")
    }

    var id: String { "\(key)" }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(key) }
    static func ==(lhs: Cell, rhs: Cell) -> Bool { lhs.key == rhs.key }
}
```

Note that I made `key` into a constant since it is the unique identifier for each cell and that I also removed `text` when conforming to the protocols because `key` is unique. And I renamed `Data` to `DataModel`

Comment: Thanks! Making `text` into a computed getter value works